# Two NICs and IP routing on CentOS

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dhcp, routing, nic

I'm trying to setup a private network but I want one of the machines to connect to both this private network and another outside network via two NICs.  I would like eth0 to be used for every IP address except for 10.0.0.1, which I would like to be accessed through eth1.  There is a DHCP and DNS server on this private network but I can't seem to get both the names on the private network and the names on the outside network to resolve. Is there a way I can make this work with the route command?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like eth0 to be used for every
>   IP address except for 10.0.0.1, which
>   I would like to be accessed through
>   eth1.

Set your routing table to:

1. route all packets for the 10.0.0.1 via eth1.

   route add -host 10.0.0.1 dev eth1
2. default route via eth0 (this is probably already done)

   route add -default dev eth0
3. check the result with `route -n` (-n disables hostname lookup)

If it works, store your settings permanently - CentOS has some [documentation here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html)

For the DNS, you will need to check `/etc/resolv.conf` to see if all DNS are listed.

Answer (score 1):

Connect both networks, but set a high metric on the interface with only 1 address. Metric is like a "cost of use" so your computer will use the lower metric interface for everything it can.

Can you post your route entries?